# A backup software for windows that backs up selected folder and maintains the destination and source identical

Tags: backup

I am looking for a backup kind of software (for windows os ) that backs up required data to external hard disk. It should 
-> Gives user the option to select the folder(s) to backup
-> If there are any changes in the source(file name renames, addition or deletion of files), the same changes should be done in the destination(in external hard) when the hard disk is connected to the system.

Answer (score 0):

That's sync software, try goodsync. It can meet your requirements like select the folders, the targeted folders change when the source change (added, edited etc).